# How to make my android app(has bluetooth connection) works without loosing connection when I press home button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

am a beginner in Android, and need to know how can I make my app that has bluetooth connection with a hardware device, not to lose the connection when I press the home button or the app is still running the service while am doing smthg else in my device. hope I could reach my point.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

When Home Button is Pressed OnPause() method is called .

So Add this method just outside onCreate ()

And Do Whatever You Want To Do .

Like Call

onPause(){ //Take this with ctrl+space

// Call onresume method here , this may work .

onResume() // take with ctrl+space

}

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    onResume();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This is bad for Android app lifecycle!

Answer (score 1):

Calling OnResume() from OnPause() is a bad idea! You're violating the android application lifecycle. I anticipate following this approach will cause problems for your app in the future.

The better option is to implement your bluetooth connection as a background service. This is the purpose of a background service - to continue running, performing tasks, even when the main application isn't in the foreground.